# Change CRON after creating webjob

Tags: azure, webjob

Once job is created to run at 8:00 AM, can I change the CRON to 1:00 AM in Azure portal not in settings.job ? If so, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The Timer trigger webjob now support `NameResolver` to bindCustom expressions, for more details you could refer to this doc: [Custom binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#custom-binding-expressions).

And if you want some sample you refer to below code or this [doc](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2017/08/dynamic-update-of-azure-web-job-time.html).

```
 namespace WebJob.Schedule
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
      config.NameResolver = new MagicResolver();
      config.UseTimers();

      JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
      host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    private class MagicResolver : INameResolver
    {
      public string Resolve(string name)
      {
        string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MagicSchedule"];              
      }
    }
  }

  public class Magic
  {
    public static void ScheduleTimeTrigger([TimerTrigger("%MagicSchedule%")] TimerInfo timer)
    {
      // Your magic web job task here
    }
  }
}
```